# Azure devops: secret naming is dynamic

Tags: azure-devops

I have a library in ADO with multiple secrets

MACHINE_A_PASS: xxxx1
MACHINE_B_PASS: xxxx2
MACHINE_C_PASS: xxxx3
MACHINE_D_PASS: xxxx4

At runtime, user selects the `$machine` variable (es MACHINE_A)

I need to concatenate `$machine` + `_PASS` and set `SQL_PASS`

I would like now to execute a SQL Command

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: "inline"
    script: |
      $query = "Select db_name()"
      Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance ${{ parameters.ServerHostName }} `
        -Username $env:xxxx `
        -Password $env:SQL_PASS `
        -Query $query `
        -TrustServerCertificate `
        -AbortOnError -OutputSqlErrors $True -Verbose
  env:
    SQL_PASS: ?????????????????
```

Is it possible in some way?